# jquery Drag and Drop - droppable area has border and draggable item won't snap to the inside of this border

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, droppable

I'm using jQuery drag and droppable to create a list of tiles plus a draggable widget which can be dropped in any of the tiles.

Each tile has a border but the widget doesn't, so although they are both the same size, when I drop the widget into the tile it snaps to the bottom left of the tile's border. Thus there is two pixels spare on the top of the tile.

Here's a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/gztQM/

and some code:

```
div[id^="row"] {float:left; width:65px; height:65px; margin:5px;border:1px solid #454545; background-color:#262e41;}
.bookmark {float:left; width:65px; height:65px; background-color:#edff57;cursor: move;display:block; margin:-1px 0px 0px -1px;}
.bookmark.ui-draggable-dragging {-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #d9d9d9; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #d9d9d9; box-shadow: 0 0 5px #d9d9d9;}
```

Here's an example of the droppable areas (tiles)

```
<div class="position" id="row-2col-1"></div>
```

the draggable link

```
<a href class="bookmark"></a>
```

the JS

```
$('.bookmark').draggable({containment: '#content', snap:'.position', snapMode:'inner', revert:'invalid',snapTolerance: 32});

$('.position').droppable({drop: handleDropEvent, accept:'.bookmark'});
function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
  var draggable = ui.draggable;
}
```

How can I get it to snap to inside the border? I've tried adding margins and paddings but to no avail. Can't see anything mentioning this on the jquery site either

Help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

It appears that the `draggable` object always snaps to the edge of `droppable` container, covering the border. This does not appear to be affected by `box-sizing` as I had previously mentioned. This behavior can even be seen in the [jQuery UI example](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to).

Your best bets are to remove the border completely, modify the behavior of the jQuery UI method to behave the way you want, or wrap each one of your `droppable` containers in a `div` that provides the margin and border styles (and remove those from the `droppable` container itself).

[jsfiddle (Wrapped Example)](http://jsfiddle.net/X5gnN/)

**Original Answer:**

I believe this might have to do with the border actually affecting the inner snapping (`snapMode:'inner'`) of the boxes due to the box model.

You can get around that by either not having a border on the boxes or by using [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing) which will change how the box model behaves. Keep in mind, that versions of IE before IE8 do not support using box-sizing without a polyfill.

```
div[id^="row"] {
    float:left;
    width:65px;
    height:65px;
    margin:5px;
    border:1px solid #454545;
    background-color:#262e41;
    /* support Firefox, WebKit, Opera and IE8+ */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QTwqt/1/)

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the reply. I tried this but it just makes the droppable areas smaller. So that when the link is dropped in there then it covers over the border. If I make the droppable slightly bigger to compensate the problem of the offset comes back

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox You are correct. I have added an update section to my answer with a work-around. This seems to be the default behavior of `droppable` and `draggable` with no apparent exposed option.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for helping me out with this, looks like it can't happen the way I was hoping. I reckon I'll do the wrapper around the tile with styles. Thanks again for the help friend